# Unable to understand a linq query 

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query in linq but i am unable to understand it, because i didn't write this query. The query is below

```
string[] arr1 = new string[]
                        {
                            "Pakistan:4,India:3,USA:2,Iran:1,UK:0",
                            "Pakistan:4,India:3,USA:2,Iran:1,UK:0",
                            "India:4,USA:3,Iran:2,UK:1,Pakistan:0"
                        };

        var count = arr1
            .SelectMany(s => s.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            .GroupBy(s => s.Split(':')[0], s => s.Split(':')[1])
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
                 g =>
                 {
                     var items = g.Distinct();
                     var result = new Dictionary<String, int>();
                     foreach (var item in items)
                         result[item] = g.Count(gitem => gitem == item);
                     return result;
                 });


        // print the result
        foreach (var country in count.Keys)
        {
            foreach (var ocurrence in count[country].Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1} = {2}", country, ocurrence, count[country][ocurrence]);
            }
        }
```

**Purpose of this query**

this query is performed to achieve this: We want to know that how many times Pakistan comes with '0' , how many times with '1' ,2 ,3 , 4 , and we want to get this information for all countries . Please can anyone define it step by step .Thanks

Note : this query is compiled , has no errors and is working properly

Comment: Have you tried to read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) for each of the methods?

Comment: actually , i asked a question on stack overflow and someone gives me that answer but i am unable to understand this . I read the documentation but didn't get anything helping on my situation

Comment: have you used Linq queries before?

Comment: No , this is why i am unable to understand

Comment: I **disagree** that this is "too localized".  This is a complex Linq query compared to the Getting Started tutorials.  It is instructive for any Linq beginner to see such a query dissected, even if it's not a query *they* are working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the query, step by step

[SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) takes the result of splitting on ',' and combines the various splits back into a single IEnumerable

> Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence.

So at that stage, you have converted the array `arr1` into a single `IEnumerable<string>` with values like like `USA:2`

[GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) then groups that `IEnumberable<string>`.  It splits each entry like `USA:2` using the ':' character.  The left-hand side is the grouping key and the right-hand side is the value.

> Groups the elements of a sequence according to a specified key selector function.

[ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx) transforms that grouping into a Dictionary.  The key of the Dictionary entry is the grouping key (e.g. `USA`).  The value of the Dictionary entry is a new (anonymous) object:

```
g =>
             {
                 var items = g.Distinct();
                 var result = new Dictionary<String, int>();
                 foreach (var item in items)
                     result[item] = g.Count(gitem => gitem == item);
                 return result;
             }
```

The anonymous object is constructed by going through and counting the unique occurrences of a given count (e.g. if the key is `USA`, how many times is the value `1`) and returns that count.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = arr1
        .SelectMany(s => s.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
```

The above method try to split Items by , so it will fetch each item indivisually for next process like Pakistan:4 , India:3

```
        .GroupBy(s => s.Split(':')[0], s => s.Split(':')[1])
```

This  Groupby is joining all same country with their count like Pakistan,4 and Pakistan ,0 in one group and India,3 and India,4 in other group like for others.

```
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
```

Now It is considering Key one by one by like first it take pakistan,Indian,Iran etc.

```
             g =>
             {
                 var items = g.Distinct();
```

This items makes its Count entries into ItemCollection like for Pakistan contains 4,0 in Enumerable for next calculation.

```
                 var result = new Dictionary<String, int>();
                 foreach (var item in items)
                     result[item] = g.Count(gitem => gitem == item);
```

Fetch item one by one and also store in result variable, g.count is now checking that how many entries are there for same count for example pakistan have 4 two times and 0 single time, same like India have 3 two times and 4 one time.

```
                 return result;
             });
```

Rest is fetching code and showing on console.